# How to sort all but first column in WPF DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have a WPF DataGrid that in its first column holds a number that is the "ranking" or "position". What I want is that when I click on a column to sort the table based on that column, for the first column to stay as-is.

For example:

```
Position  Name   Games   Points    PPG
1         John   2       10        5
2         Mary   3       12        4
```

when sorted by Games in descending order should become

```
Position  Name   Games   Points    PPG
1         Mary   3       12        4
2         John   2       10        5
```

Is there a way to do this? DataColumn doesn't seem to have any such property, and FreezeColumnsCount only retains them in view at all times, but doesn't stop them from being sorted along with the rest of the data.

Comment: if you're getting your data from a database you can use your sql to sort it in the order by clause, other than that if you use a datagridview this functionality is built in without any code required.

Comment: @justin-kirk I'm using a database, but I don't want to do SQL requests all the time since the functionality is there in the clickable column headers. And I'm not using a DataGridView, but a WPF DataGrid. Are you still sure the functionality is built-in? How can I keep the first column as is then even after the sort?

Comment: The functionality exists,.... but if you're a beginner to xaml i highly recommend using sql. Writing out a decent solution give me a second

Comment: I would use a DataGridRowHeader instead of a DataGridColumn for showing Position.

Comment: Does the user need to edit the cells?

Comment: @Blam, no, not really. It's a read-only column. Actually, the whole table is read-only.

Comment: @LPL, that sounds interesting. I'll have to take a look. Do DataGridRowHeaders stay put even after a sort?

Comment: Then I would do a ListView GridView and handle the click event on the header to sort.  Use LINQ to sort.  Then renumber the order column.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/ffd7037d-dd77-44ec-9011-d0d43d5706aa/ I just found an example (answer from Adbie) for what I suggested in my comment:

```
<DataGrid LoadingRow="dg_LoadingRow">
    <DataGrid.RowHeaderTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Header, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGridRow}}}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGrid.RowHeaderTemplate>
</DataGrid>
```

```
private void dg_LoadingRow(object sender, DataGridRowEventArgs e)
{
    e.Row.Header = (e.Row.GetIndex() + 1).ToString();
}
```

**EDIT by OP:**
I've just verified it works even without the binding. The cs code is fine, but in XAML you only need to do

```
<DataGrid LoadingRow="dg_LoadingRow" />
```

Comment: This looks much simpler than my solution.  Is the binding really necessary?  It appears you are binding the RowHeaderTemplate to display the Row Header.  This seems redundant.  What does the default RowHeaderTemplate look like?

Comment: At the moment I'm away and can't test it by myself. Maybe there is room for further improvement.

Comment: Thanks for this. So much simpler. Another lesson learned, another problem solved! I've edited the answer to show that binding isn't necessary, just like @cadrell0 guessed. Feel free to incorporate the edit into your answer if you want.

Comment: @cadrell0 Wow, it's even simpler then I thougth. Thanks for your cooperation, now it's really an ingenious solution.

Answer (score 3):

I would use a `ValueConverter` for this.  I can't tell you exactly how to do it, however, what you are going to want to look at is the property [`ItemContainerGenerator`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemcontainergenerator.aspx) on the DataGrid.

Add a `DataGrid` property to your ValueConverter so that you have access to that from the Convert method.  Now, in convert, you will need to call `ContainerFromItem` to get the UI object, then `IndexFromContainer` to get the index of the row.  I'm sure you will run into some issues, but this should get your started.

The nice part about this is that you don't have to do your own sorting.  This will rely on the `SortDescriptions` that are added to the `ICollectionView`(if you don't bind to one, it is created automatically for you) used by the DataGrid.

**Edit**

Here is the requested code example.  I have not had a need to do this myself, but this is where I would start.

Here is how the proposed value converted might look

```
public ItemPositionValueConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public DataGrid DataGrid { get; set; }

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value == null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        if (DataGrid == null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        ItemContainerGenerator generator = DataGrid.ItemContainerGenerator;
        return generator.IndexFromContainer(generator.ContainerFromItem(value));
    }

    //you probably don't need ConvertBack put it is provided for completeness
    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        int? index = value as int?

        if (index == null)
        {
            return null
        }

        if (DataGrid == null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        ItemContainerGenerator generator = DataGrid.ItemContainerGenerator;
        return generator.ItemFromContainer(generator.ContainerFromIndex(index.Value));
    }
}
```

Now to use this do something like.

```
<UserControl>
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <ItemPositionValueConverter x:Key=ItemPositionValueConverter"
                                    DataGrid="{Binding ElementName=MyDataGrid}" />
    </UserControl.Resources>

    <DataGrid x:Name="MyDataGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding ....}">
        <DataGrid.Columns> 
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Position"
                                Binding="{Binding Converter={StaticResource ItemPositionValueConverter}}"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
</UserControl>
```

Note, with this solution, there is no need to manually add sorting to the ICollectionView.  When you click on the column header, the sorting will be applied automatically.

**Disclaimer: This code has note been tested and may not function exactly as described.  It is provider here to demonstrate the logic required.  As such it may contain typos or bugs.  Anyone attempting to use this code should perform their own tests to verify it suites their needs.

Comment: Provide some sort of code example ? what you've provided to someone who doesn't already know the answer to the question is too unclear : give this a read http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7656/how-do-i-write-a-good-answer-to-a-question , Let it be noted this is not a troll attempt; I'm also interested as I'm using my code above as a sorting mechanism and since it's 'not parameterized' I'm curious on how i can improve it.

Comment: Voted up; Might remove vote when i test it out if i can't get it to work (>^_^)>

Comment: It amazes me that there's no easier way to actually have a column stay as-is during a sort. I'll have to do a lot of reading up if I'm to actually understand any of this. Thanks for taking the time to answer though, @cadrell0.

Answer (score 0):

**New Answer:**

so my last answer was obviously not up to standard, i have done some research and it looks like you can do what you're looking for like this :

```
 Dim view As ICollectionView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(ListViewName.Items)
 view.SortDescriptions.Add(New SortDescription("Field To Sort By", 0))
```

**Where**

- 'Field to Sort By' is the column Name
- # is the direction 0 being Ascending, 1 being Descending

**Note:**

- You must call view.SortDescriptions.Clear() in between changing sort orders of the same column in the list

Comment: Sorting is the easy part.  Getting the row numbers that don't change when the sort changes is the real challenge.

Comment: Yeah, that was kind of the point of the question. I'm familiar with sorting data. I know how to do it in SQL, and I know how to properly set column types so that the DataGrid sorts itself correctly. LPL answered my question. Thanks for taking the time to answer though.